# Replace little c sharp depreciation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code written with C# for Unity3D. The problem is I have Unity 5 and the code was written for an older version so there are things I have to replace because they are obsolete. With the folloiwng code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton (1) && (!requireLock || controlLock || Screen.lockCursor))
// If the right mouse button is held, rotation is locked to the mouse
{
    if (controlLock)
    {
        Screen.lockCursor = true;
    }

    rotationAmount = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * mouseTurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
else
{
    if (controlLock)
    {
        Screen.lockCursor = false;
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> CS0618: `UnityEngine.Screen.lockCursor' is obsolete:`Property
>   lockCursor has been deprecated. Use Cursor.lockState and
>   Cursor.visible instead.'

If I will replace lockCursor with lockState it is not working.

How do I update the obsolete code correctly?

Comment: Try to replace properly yourself, then if it's not working post that code and you'll receive help.

Comment: What do you mean by "If I will repleace lockCursor with lockCursor not working."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look on Unity's site, they mention what you are supposed to do as the alternative.

Try the following:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton (1) && (!requireLock || controlLock || Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked))
// If the right mouse button is held, rotation is locked to the mouse
{
    if (controlLock)
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    rotationAmount = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * mouseTurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
else
{
    if (controlLock)
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: is good but the screen does not work "does not contain a definition for `visible' and 'lockState '" any idea?

Comment: my bad, it should be Cursor instead. try that

Answer (score 1):

You should use enum insted of boolean value:

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
Cursor.visible = false;
```

Here you can find possible values which you can set:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html

Comment: "does not contain a definition for `visible' and 'lockState '" any idea?

Comment: Do you use Cursor class instead of Screen class?